# Qual a melhor forma de fazer login com Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, api, session, ionic, login

Em um app utilizando AngularJS e Ionic, qual a melhor forma de fazer autenticação em uma API? Faço a verificação de login em todas as telas ou utilizo algum mecanismo de sessão?

Imagino que fazer autenticação em todas as controllers talvez consuma dados demais... Qual o melhor caminho?

Answer (score 5):

O ideal é utilizar APIs que suportam OAuth 2, você então realiza os procedimentos iniciais para obter o *bearer token* e o armazena em um *cookie* para ser utilizado em toda requisição à API (ou pelo menos aos *endpoints* que requerem essa autenticação). Vou te dar um exemplo de um *service* que estou utilizando em uma aplicação para realizar todos os procedimentos autenticação com uma API que faz uso do OAuth 2.

Aqui está o código do *service*:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('zigforumApp')
        .service('users', users);

    users.$inject = ['$http', '$cookies', 'TOKEN_URL'];

    function users($http, $cookies, TOKEN_URL) {
        var sv = this;

        function NoAuthenticationException(message) {
            this.name = 'AuthenticationRequired';
            this.message = message;
        }

        function AuthenticationExpiredException(message) {
            this.name = 'AuthenticationExpired';
            this.message = message;
        }

        function AuthenticationRetrievalException(message) {
            this.name = 'AuthenticationRetrieval';
            this.message = message;
        }

        sv.userData = {
            isAuthenticated: false,
            username: '',
            bearerToken: '',
            expirationDate: null
        };

        function isAuthenticationExpired(expirationDate) {
            var now = new Date();
            expirationDate = new Date(expirationDate);

            if (expirationDate - now > 0) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }

        function saveData() {
            removeData();
            $cookies.putObject('auth_data', sv.userData);
        }

        function removeData() {
            $cookies.remove('auth_data');
        }

        function retrieveSavedData() {
            var savedData = $cookies.getObject('auth_data');

            if (typeof savedData === 'undefined') {
                throw new AuthenticationRetrievalException('No authentication data exists');
            } else if (isAuthenticationExpired(savedData.expirationDate)) {
                throw new AuthenticationExpiredException('Authentication token has already expired');
            } else {
                sv.userData = savedData;
                setHttpAuthHeader();
            }
        }

        function clearUserData() {
            sv.userData.isAuthenticated = false;
            sv.userData.username = '';
            sv.userData.bearerToken = '';
            sv.userData.expirationDate = null;
        }

        function setHttpAuthHeader() {
            $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + sv.userData.bearerToken;
        }

        this.isAuthenticated = function () {
            if (!(sv.userData.isAuthenticated && !isAuthenticationExpired(sv.userData.expirationDate))) {
                try {
                    retrieveSavedData();
                } catch (e) {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        };

        this.removeAuthentication = function () {
            removeData();
            clearUserData();
            $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = null;
        };

        this.authenticate = function (username, password, persistData, successCallback, errorCallback) {
            this.removeAuthentication();
            var config = {
                method: 'POST',
                url: TOKEN_URL,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                },
                data: 'grant_type=password&username=' + username + '&password=' + password
            };

            $http(config)
                .success(function (data) {
                    sv.userData.isAuthenticated = true;
                    sv.userData.username = data.userName;
                    sv.userData.bearerToken = data.access_token;
                    sv.userData.expirationDate = new Date(data['.expires']);
                    setHttpAuthHeader();
                    if (persistData === true) {
                        saveData();
                    }
                    if (typeof successCallback === 'function') {
                        successCallback();
                    }
                })
                .error(function (data) {
                    if (typeof errorCallback === 'function') {
                        if (data && data.error_description) {
                            errorCallback(data.error_description);
                        } else {
                            errorCallback('Unable to contact server; please, try again later.');
                        }
                    }
                });
        };

        try {
            retrieveSavedData();
        } catch (e) { }
    }
})();
```

A função mais importante é a `authenticate` ela recebe os dados de login do usuário, faz uma requisição à API para obter o *token*, armazena o *token* em um *cookie* e para autenticar automaticamente todas as requisições que serão feitas daqui em diante ele adiciona esse *token* como *header* padrão.

Você pode utilizar esse service como base para montar o seu.

Comment: Boa @Zignd! Farei uma implementação utilizando OAuth2 e seguindo seu exemplo de código. Obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

A melhor forma de fazer login com AngularJS é...

## Não faça login com angularJS.

Sério. Sendo uma tecnologia que é executada no cliente, toda e qualquer regra de validação de credenciais (conexão a um *endpoint* para verificar usuário e senha, por exemplo) pode ser explorada por um usuário malicioso.

A melhor maneira, neste caso, envolveria delegar a responsabilidade de ações de sign-in e sign-out para outra parte da aplicação - no exemplo bem-dado por [Zignd](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/263/zignd), esta tecnologia seria [OAuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth).

O resultado final de uma antenticação via OAuth é um *token*, que pode ser armazenado em LocalStorage ou em um cookie. Utilize este *token* para obter informações a respeito do usuário atualmente logado.

Comment: Certo @Ibotinelly, tenho uma autenticação em dois passos em uma api... Vou buscar implementar o padrão OAuth2. Obrigado.

Comment: @MaurílioNovais Não por isso - sinta-se à vontade para postar mais perguntas quando as dúvidas a respeito da implementação começarem a aparecer. Neste post (em inglês) são fornecidos vários links que podem ajudar nas suas pesquisas iniciais: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29660828/custom-oauth-server-implementation-and-its-advantages